# yarnpkg add --exact react react-dom react-scripts cra-template --cwd /Users/user/Desktop/app has failed

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app, npx

I'm trying to run `npx create-react-app app` but everytime throws the error `yarnpkg add --exact react react-dom react-scripts cra-template --cwd /Users/user/Desktop/app has failed`

node -v `v16.14.0`

npm -v `8.3.1`

yarn -v `1.22.17`

Tried to uninstall node, npm and yarn but still doesn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `yarn` then try running `yarn --ignore-engines` in your terminal.